# What is the meaning of peotic sentence about woman's dresses?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Aaron say this words to Robert about woman's dresses:

> I had this girl, Tina. She said the **dress made the woman**. I say the
>   woman makes the dress.

Sentence is taken from movie *Entrapment (1999)*, My Doubt: How can a Dress(non-living) made the Woman(living creature)?

I heard English sentences earlier like this:  **Dress made woman beautiful**, but above sentence doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's one of those *"Does the woman make the dress or does the dress make the woman?"* questions.

The simple explanation is that "*perfect dressing will always identify your personality*". This is an idiom much like "*[clothes make the man](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Clothes+make+the+man)*"

Comment: I recall there was also "the suit makes the man".

Comment: @JorgeUrreta ah, yeh, that one is true too.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, the term 'make' means to make beautiful or attractive. Underlying meaning of the movie quote is, that while his girl Tina believed women are made beautiful by beautiful clothing, he, Robert, believes that a woman inherently makes the clothing beautiful. The subtext is defining Robert's tendency to exalt the beauty of women and to find women inherently beautiful. Robert pays all women a compliment by making the statement.

Comment: According to OP, ***Aaron** said these words* (to Robert). Robert just listened.

Comment: I think you're reading too much into this, Amanda_M, when you say that a compliment is being paid to all women.  We could use different terms: The coach makes the team.  The team makes the coach.  There is no inherent compliment there to "all teams" or to all coaches.  Rather, it is simply flipping the assertion: The success of the team depends on the coach. The success of the coach depends on the team.  Whether a dress will look good depends on the woman wearing it. Whether a woman will look good depends on the dress she is wearing.

Comment: My answer: watch the movie